# Wix installer msi rollback on another machine and working fine in local development machine

Tags: wix, installation

I created a wix installer which is working fine in local machine but when I try to install it on another machine it rollback at the end.During installation process I can see installed folder on other machines as well. Following is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:iis="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/iis"
     >
    <!-- The name of the product -->
  <?define WindowServiceName = "Gatac Window Service" ?>
  <!-- The manufacturer, for setup package publisher and folder info -->
  <?define Manufacturer = "GAT" ?>
  <Product Id="*" Name="Time Attendance Setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="GAT" UpgradeCode="3bd1aa4d-5ff8-4f82-8e46-2dda5daec90d" >
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <!-- Prerequiest -->
    <PropertyRef Id="IISMAJORVERSION"/>
    <Condition Message="Install requires IIS 7 or latest.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (IISMAJORVERSION AND (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" OR IISMAJORVERSION = "#10"))]]>
    </Condition>

    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45" />
    <Condition Message="This application requires  .NETFramework 4.5. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
    </Condition>

    <!-- Prerequiest -->

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WebPortalSetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebWebComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef  Id="GatWebsiteIssConfiguration" />
      <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent'/>
      <ComponentRef Id="WindowsServiceHost" />
    </Feature>
    <!-- Specify UI -->
    <UIRef Id="MyUI" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <Property Id="IISROOT">
      <RegistrySearch Id="IISROOT"
                      Type="directory"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="Software\Microsoft\InetStp"
                      Name="PathWWWRoot" />
    </Property>


    <!-- Will default to C:\ if that is the main disk-->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <!-- Will reference to C:\inetpub-->
      <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name="WebDir">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="GATAC">

        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='InstallDir' Name='Acme'>

        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <!--Create a folder inside Talk Sharp called Test Service-->
          <Directory Id="INSTALLERFOLDER" Name="$(var.WindowServiceName)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

    </Directory>




  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Comment: run "msiexec /i Installer.msi /l*v log.txt" in the cmd line to make a log file which will greatly help in your search for why this install is failing.

Comment: @BrianSutherland for you comment I checked log and it was giving error while executing connection string and for that I just remove user attribute from sql:SqlScript to sql:SqlDatabase and it works on other machine as well now. But for me it is strange till now why it working when I move user attribute to sql:SqlDatabase